# How to use regex in lucene query elasticsearch?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, grafana, regexp-replace

I am working in grafana and using elasticsearch as datasource. I have a dropdown filter in grafana to filter the value. The dropdown values like `"string1_dev_01","string1_prod_01","string2_dev_02","string2_prod_02"`. Here I use template variable to pass selected value to lucene query,

```
template variable name = version_name

column name in elastic search = version
```

Lucene Query : `version:$version_name`

When I select `string1_dev_01` it fetches data belongs to `string1_dev_01`.

But I want, when selecting either `string1_dev_01` or `string1_prod_01` it should fetch all data belongs to both the dev and prod.

Note: In filter, I want to show the data like `string1_*_01` and `string2_*_02` and value should assign to template variable like

```
version_name = "string1_*_01"
```

Here how can I achieve this? Are there any possibilities to use regex or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design the template variable with the exact regex.
The following template variable can work with version_name as "string1_"*"_01" as it's value.
Lucene query: version: "$version_name".

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for the regex to replace the existing value. Any idea how to do it in Lucene query or template variable in grafana?

Comment: I have added the regex expression in my answer. The query should be version: "$version_name". The template variable in the JSON should be:                        
 "text": "string1_*_01",
 "value": "string1_\"*\"_01"